# Как затемнить картинку и наложить текст с логотипом посредством php?

Tags: php, gd, jpeg

Вот такой код есть

```
  <?php

    // Тип содержимого
    header('Content-Type: image/png');

    // Создание изображения
    $im = imagecreatetruecolor(1200, 630);

    // Создание цветов
    $white = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
    $grey = imagecolorallocate($im, 128, 128, 128);
    $black = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
    imagefilledrectangle($im, 0, 0, 399, 29, $white);

    // Текст надписи
    $text = 'test';
    // Замена пути к шрифту на пользовательский
    $font = '/var/www/www-root/data/www/mycrimea.online/wp-content/themes/publisher-child/globerbold.ttf';

    // Тень
    imagettftext($im, 20, 0, 11, 21, $grey, $font, $text);

    // Текст
    imagettftext($im, 20, 0, 10, 20, $black, $font, $text);

    imagepng($im);
    imagedestroy($im);
    ?>
```

но как не создать картинку а наложить уже на имеющуюся сначала фон полупрозрачный, а потом уже поверх текст с логотипом?
[image: пример как хочу сделать]

Comment: php умет многое, но для ui лучше использовать css, а с помощью php генерировать необходимый html

Comment: мне нужно выводить отдельные картинки когда репостят в соц сети

Comment: тогда js с этим справиться. php этого сделать не сможет, потому что при окончании загрузки страницы, php прекращает работу.

Comment: @SegreiUlanov кто сказал? Как раз данную задачу нужно решать именно с помощью PHP или любым другим методом, на стороне сервера, а не у клиента (сжирать его RAM/CPU каждый раз). При добавлении материала на сайт или при первой загрузки страницы  генерируется подобная картинка, посредством того же PHP и сохраняется на сервере. При последующих обращениях к данной странице уже подставляется всего лишь ссылка на картинку. Если речь о картинках для постов в социальных сетях, то добавляете его в **`<meta property="og:image" content="__HERE__">`** тег.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для удобства, загрузили весь набор в [**Github**](https://github.com/perfectoweb/stackoverflow/tree/master/og-images-generator). Ниже код и картинки до/после.

```
<?
    $img            = imagecreatefrompng("res/source.png");
    $img_cover      = imagecreatefrompng("res/transparent.png");
    $img_logo       = imagecreatefrompng("res/logo.png");
    $font_path      = "ptsans.ttf";
    $font_path_bold = "ptsans-bold.ttf";
    $save_file      = "output/".uniqid().'.png';
    $quality        = 80;
    $temp           = "";

    $date           = "25.07.2018, 15:00";
    $title          = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit";

    /*-----------------------------------------------------------------
    | Накладываем полупрозрачный фон
    ------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    imagealphablending($img, true);
    imagesavealpha($img, true);
    imagealphablending($img_cover, true);
    imagesavealpha($img_cover, true);    
    imagecopy($img, $img_cover, 0, 0, 0, 0, imagesx($img_cover), imagesy($img_cover));



    /*-----------------------------------------------------------------
    | Накладываем лого
    ------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    imagealphablending($img, true);
    imagesavealpha($img, true);
    imagealphablending($img_logo, true);
    imagesavealpha($img_logo, true);
    imagecopy($img, $img_logo, 44, 44, 0, 0, imagesx($img_logo), imagesy($img_logo));


    /*-----------------------------------------------------------------
    | Накладываем текст и дату
    ------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    $line = array(32, 64, 96);

    if (mb_strlen($title) > $line[0]) {

        $pos = mb_strlen(explode(' ', mb_substr($title, $line[0], 999), 2)[0]);
        $line[0] = $pos+$line[0];

    }
    if (mb_strlen($title) > $line[1]) {

        $pos = mb_strlen(explode(' ', mb_substr($title, $line[1], 999), 2)[0]);
        $line[1] = $pos+$line[1];

    }
    if (mb_strlen($title) > $line[0]) {
        $title = mb_substr($title, 0, $line[0])."\n".mb_substr($title, $line[0]+1, $line[1]-$line[0])."\n".mb_substr($title, $line[1]+1, $line[0]);
    }


    # Add date
    $color = imagecolorallocate($img, 155, 192, 239);
    $text = $date;
    imagettftext($img, 12, 0, 44, 152, $color, $font_path, $text);

    # Add City
    $color = imagecolorallocate($img, 155, 192, 239);
    $text = mb_strtoupper($city);
    imagettftext($img, 12, 0, 260, 151, $color, $font_path_bold, $text);

    # Add Title
    $color = imagecolorallocate($img, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF);
    $text = $title;
    imagettftext($img, 24, 0, 44, 214, $color, $font_path_bold, $text);


    # Save Image
    imagepng($img, $save_file, 9);
    imagedestroy($img);             

?>
```

**До:** 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**После:**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]